# ADFS : Acquiring token with PromptBehavior.Auto

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

As per the [Documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively---Public-client-application-flows#properties-or-platformparameters-constructors-parameters-common-to-most-platforms) of `PromptBehavior.Auto`, I understand that :

> If no token exists in the cache, but the user is known, or a session
>   cookie is available in the web browser control used for the
>   interaction, the dialog `flashes but disappears immediately`.

But, is there a way to suppress this Dialog completely, because 1st time when I call `AcquireTokenAsync` and if it takes time to return the token, the Blank Dialog does not appear as a flash (as in document above), instead it stays for the entire period till the token is returned. In subsequent calls, it does not happen as I have already acquired the token and it is present in the cache.

Is there a way to suppress/hide it completely in case of `PromptBehavior = Auto` ?

---

***Note that:*** `PromptBehavior = Never` is not an option as per the Doc

> If you use PromptBehavior = Never and the token does not exist in the
>   cache, or needs to be refreshed with UI, the call to AcquireTokenAsync
>   will fail with an exception of type AdalException

Answer (score 2):

You can call [AcquireTokenSilentAsync](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token) first.

The [recommended pattern](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token#recommended-pattern-to-acquire-a-token) for public client applications (desktop/mobile apps) in ADAL.NET is:

```
try
{
 result = await ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId);
}
catch (AdalException adalException)
{
 if (adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently
     || adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.InteractionRequired)
  {
   result = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId,redirectUri,
                                       new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that exactly. *1st time* the dialog will appear / flash in any case no matter what because `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` will fail. And it will go to exception and then try to fetch using `AcquireTokenAsync` - this will flash the Browser dialog. Subsequent calls will not. (as already mentioned in the question). So question is how should I suppress the Dialog completely ?

Comment: On which platform are you? .NET Framework? .NET Core? Xamarin.Android? Xamarin.iOS? UWP?
If you are on .NET Framework or .NET core (I suppose you are), you need to implement a [token cache serialization](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Token-cache-serialization), this way you will see the dialog the very first usage of the application, but then the token will be in the cache which will be serialized, and re-hydrated. The link I provided above contains links to samples implementing such a cache

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5. I do not want to see the Dialog in 1st usage - that is my point. I know it pops up now because token is not in cache. But can we enhance the api so that alongwith PropmtBehaviour.Auto, I can pass `false' to hide the dialog ?

Comment: @Angshuman. I'm confused. If you don't want see the dialog ever, that means you don't want to use an interactive flow. would you be writing an app that works on Windows? in that case you might want to use the [windows integrated authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos)) ?

Comment: I am on Windows & I tried that. It throws exception - `{"There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Internal.OAuth2.TokenResponse. Encountered unexpected character '<'."}` Also there is a comment on this method which says - `This feature is supported only for Azure Active Directory and Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) on Windows 10.`